# QueryString Link

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following code which works for a postbackurl on a button. What I need to do is do something similar, but with an:

```
<a href></a>
```

in asp.net. How can I do that? Thanks for your help!

```
<a href="negativestorydetail.aspx?tag=<%# Eval("Tag") %>" style="color: #ff0000; text-align: center; margin: 15px; line-height: 30px; text-decoration:none; font-size: <%# GetTagSize(Convert.ToDouble(Eval("weight"))) %>"><%# Eval("Tag") %></a>
```

C# CODE:

```
protected string GenerateLinkDetails(object companyId, object projectName, object projectId) { 

    return string.Format("~/projectdetails.aspx?guid={0}&name={1}&role={2}&member={3}&company={4}&project={5}&proj_id={6}", id, name, company_role, mem_id, companyId, projectName, projectId); 
}
```

ASP.NET CODE:

```
<asp:Button ID="LinkButtonDetails" runat="server" Text="DETAILS" PostBackUrl='<%# GenerateLinkDetails(Eval("CompanyID"), Eval("ProjectName"), Eval("ProjectID")) %>' />
```

Comment: what is wrong with the href you have posted in your question?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LinkButton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.aspx) instead. It's an ASP.Net server control and a hyperlink.